# how to convert enum to string property with help of humanizer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, enums, humanizer

I have a model thats is for db (codeFirst approach)

```
    public class Request : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Uuid { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Status Status { get; set; }

        public string StatusName { get; set; }


        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I want when I fill my Status enum to automatically set property StatusName in the way that grabs which enum type is and to convert it to string with Humanizer.

My try was as follows:

```
...set { return ((Status[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))).Select(x => new String() { x.ToString() })); }; } but with no success.
```

Comment: Are you trying set `StatusName` on setter of `Status` property?

Comment: yes with Humanizer

Comment: "I want when I fill my Status enum to automatically set property StatusName in the way that grabs which enum type is and to convert it to string with Humanizer." From your description, it seems that when you create a new Request, after selected the state from the State enum, you want to set the StatusName property using the selected value, right? If that is the case, why not do this action in the Create View Page, in that page, you could use a `<select>` to display the enum records, you could check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgdyI.gif).